# h:graphicImage value tag parses spaces as +

Tags: jsf-2, el

i have a file name that contains spaces: `bw3 - Copy_1340627264571.jpg`
and i use this name to load the image as follows:

```
<h:graphicImage value="/#{myBean.imageFolder}/#{image.name}" width="30" height="30" style="border:0;"/>
```

this is translated to:

```
<img width="30" height="30" style="border:0;" src="/MyAPP/image/bw3+-+Copy_1340627264571.jpg">
```

while if i tried to print the name in outputText, it's printed correctly:

```
<h:outputText  value="#{image.name}"/>
```

this is translated to:

```
<span id="myForm:viewImagesTable:0:_t68">bw3 - Copy_1340627264571.jpg</span>
```

any ideas how to fix that ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This seems to be a bug in `<h:graphicImage>`. Spaces in request URI should be URL-encoded as `%20` using `java.net.URI` and spaces in request query string should be URL-encoded as `+` using `java.net.URLEncoder`. It seems that `<h:graphicImage>` encodes the entire URI using `java.net.URLEncoder`.

Better replace them yourself beforehand:

```
<h:graphicImage value="/#{myBean.imageFolder}/#{image.name.replace(' ', '%20')}" />
```

Or, much better, don't allow spaces in filenames at all. When it concerns uploaded files, replace them by `_` or something before saving.

Note that this has **nothing** to do with EL as your question tagging suggest.